# How to enable the Radeon dynamic power management feature?

Tags: kernel

So recently, the RC's of Linux Kernel 3.11 were released. As you may know, this new kernel comes with dynamic power management for users of the open source Radeon driver. Since I have power management issues with the default kernel of Ubuntu 13.04, I wanted to try this out.

Doe someone know how to enable this new feature after I downloaded and installed the latest kernel RC from the Kernel Testing PPA?

EDIT: More specifically, I am talking about this: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM5NjE

Comment: 3.11 has not been released yet, and Ubuntu already has an official mirror? That's new. Do you, perhaps, mean the [kernel testing PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/)?

Comment: Yes, that's the one I mean! I downloaded the latest RC (rc2 at the time of writing) from there.

Comment: @mikewhatever: edited the question to make it more clear. In my opinion this question is not off-topic at all, I am talking about installing a new kernel in the CURRENT Ubuntu version (13.04). Can someone please clarify why this question is closed?

Comment: You're right, this should be re-opened. Apologies for the hasty (incorrect) vote to close.

Comment: @Gladen - do you mean tlp ? This normally involves power-management for accus of notebooks, and it is handling usage of power too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update (8-05-2014):** *As expected, in Ubuntu 14.04 DPM is enabled by default for all modern AMD GPU's (HD 4000 through HD 7000 series). If you are running this release together with a supported graphics card, you don't need to do anything to use this feature.*

**Update (28-11-2013):** *Ubuntu 13.10 ships with the 3.11 kernel by default. So if you are using this release, all you need to do is add the parameter to the Linux Kernel. I updated the guide accordingly. Also, it looks like by Ubuntu 14.04, DPM will be enabled by default so hopefully this guide will be obsolete by then! ;)*

Ok, In the last few days I experimented a bit and got it enabled! It's actually really easy once you found out how to do it.. For people who also want to try it, I'll explain every step. Starting with the installation of the new kernel.

First of all a few points to consider. The Radeon DPM support is only for Radeon HD 2000 (R600) series graphics cards and newer. If you're using a really old ATI Radeon graphics card, the power management support is already tapped out on the open-source driver.

**Steps for Ubuntu 13.04 or below only:**

To use Radeon DPM you need the Linux 3.11 kernel or newer. You can use the Ubuntu mainline kernel PPA and download the latest stable 3.11 Linux kernel image from [this kernel.ubuntu.com directory](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.11.10.11-saucy/). Any future kernel updates are fine too and can then also be found in this directory.

Using the dynamic power management feature requires updated firmware for the graphics card. The latest Radeon microcode/firmware can be downloaded from [this directory](http://people.freedesktop.org/~agd5f/radeon_ucode/). You need the ***_smc.bin** files from June. If you're unsure of your specific graphics card codename, you can generally find it from looking at output of **lspci -v | less** ...  The file(s) need to be placed within **/lib/firmware/radeon**. If you try to use Radeon DPM without the firmware, acceleration will end up being disabled for the GPU. You also need to make sure you have the updated firmware in **/lib/firmware/radeon** *before* installing the >3.11 kernel - it will be pulled automagically into the installed image.

**Ubuntu 13.10 or lower, or users of Radeon HD 3000 or below:**

The Radeon DPM support is not enabled by default below Linux kernel 3.13, or for older GPUs. You must add the **radeon.dpm=1** parameter to the Linux kernel to enable it in these cases. For the steps to do so on Ubuntu, see the [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters) about the different ways.

With the new kernel installed, firmware updated and Kernel parameter enabled you should be good to go. You must now reboot your system and you can check if everything is working after that by doing

**cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/64/radeon_pm_info**

**Note:** @luca992 pointed out that the file *radeon_pm_info* could be in a different directory (for example in /sys/kernel/debug/dri/1/ instead of dri/64/). If you're absolutely sure you followed all steps correctly, you can check if this could be the case in your situation.

You should see something like this:

```
uvd    vclk: 0 dclk: 0
power level 0    sclk: 22000 mclk: 25000 vddc: 900
```

You can further configure DPM by opening **/etc/rc.local** and adding the following line:

```
echo parameter > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_state
```

Where **"parameter"** can be:

- **battery** (a set of performance levels targeted for optimal operation on battery)
- **balanced** (a set of performance levels targeted for optimal every day use)
- **performance** (a set of performance levels targeted for the highest GPU performance)

*Sources:* http://www.botchco.com/agd5f/?p=57

Comment: Got to say.. battery life on my laptop is now just as good as with the proprietary drivers. Also performance should be a bit better as a side effect of being able to reclock to higher speeds on heavier loads. I'm impressed with the results!

Comment: If you get `command not found: glxinfo`. Then it isn't installed. To install, do `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`.

Comment: What is the name of apt package that needs to be installed?

Comment: "If you are running this release together with a supported graphics card, you don't need to do anything to use this feature." – Except the default setting is 'balanced', so you may want to switch to 'battery' if you want to minimize power consumption.

Comment: In 15.04 (Radeon HD 4850) `/sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_method` says `profile` and will not accept `dynamic` unless also enabled on the kernel command line.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, I'm going to part from the presumption you already have the kernel 3.11-GIT and have a r6xx-SI or newer ATI card. From there on, you just have to add `radeom.dpm=1`  as a kernel module parameter and DPM should be activated.

It could be either in the GRUB parameter, in the `/etc/default/grub` file write

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet radeon.dpm=1"
sudo update-grub
```

Or in a `.conf` file under your `/etc/modprobe` directory:

```
sudo su -
touch /etc/modprobe.d/radeon-dpm.conf
echo options radeon dpm=1 > /etc/modprobe.d/radeon-dpm.conf 
cat /etc/modprobe.d/radeon-dpm.conf 
# will output "options radeon dpm=1"
```

Quote from the sources:

> The AMD Radeon driver finally has dynamic power management support! For Radeon GPUs the core clock and memory clocks will dynamically adjust (along with the voltages) based upon load, this works for multi-monitor configurations, and it's at near feature parity to what's provided by PowerPlay and the features in the AMD Catalyst driver. This is a big win for saving on power/battery when using the open-source Radeon Linux driver along with offering better performance for newer GPUs that have a boot clock speed that's lower than their rated frequencies. This support goes back to Radeon HD 2000 (R600) GPUs but is currently not enabled by default but requires setting **radeon.dpm=1.**

Sources:

- http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/dri-devel/2013-June/040436.html
- http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amd_radeon_dpm&num=1
- http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQwNjA
- http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=amd_dpm_preview&num=1

Comment: don't forget: 'sudo update-grub' after doing 'GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet radeon.dpm=1"'

Comment: dude, you have no idea how helpful this was for me to fix an ATI HD 4890 graphics card on Manjaro.  THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

In case tlp meets your intentions :

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw

For thinkpads it is :

> sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-tools

When am not wrong - tlp is not inmediately dependent on the kernel-version - it depends more on the hardware. Between Kernel 3.11 and Kernel 3.10 are no wildly differences.

In article of phoronix is listed about the new changes in Kernel 3.11 :

http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQwODk

But in 3.11 there are no changes about the power-management in general.

I think the dynamic power-management changes for Radeon affect only the support with power-supply of the graphics card.

After installation tlp is to start with :

> sudo tlp start

Comment: Thanks for the response! But that is not exactly what I mean. There actually is power management as you can read in this article on Phoronix: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTM5NjE

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gladen's answer I thought I would make an additional commit on verifying dpm is working to save others some frustration.

In my case

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/64/radeon_pm_info
```

does not exist so I thought dpm was not working.

However apparently that file is just in different folders for me.

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/65/radeon_pm_info
```

or

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/1/radeon_pm_info
```

both exist and list the same info.

Comment: it is now `/sys/kernel/debug/dri/0/amdgpu_pm_info`

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the answer from @Gladen, I found that

```
echo parameter > /sys/class/drm/card0/device/power_dpm_state
```

didn't work.  A quick `ls -l /sys/class/drm/` showed me that card0 refers to the integrated card & card1 to the discrete card. So the following works for me on card1:

```
$ sudo -i

# cat /sys/class/drm/card1/device/power_dpm_state
balanced
# cat /sys/class/drm/card1/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level  
auto
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/1/radeon_pm_info
uvd    vclk: 0 dclk: 0
power level 0    sclk: 15700 mclk: 20000 vddc: 900 vddci: 0
#
# echo "battery" > /sys/class/drm/card1/device/power_dpm_state
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/1/radeon_pm_info
uvd    vclk: 0 dclk: 0
power level 0    sclk: 15700 mclk: 20000 vddc: 900 vddci: 0
#
# echo "low" > /sys/class/drm/card1/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level  
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/1/radeon_pm_info
uvd    vclk: 0 dclk: 0
power level 0    sclk: 15700 mclk: 20000 vddc: 900 vddci: 0
# echo "performance" > /sys/class/drm/card1/device/power_dpm_state
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/1/radeon_pm_info
uvd    vclk: 0 dclk: 0
power level 0    sclk: 15700 mclk: 20000 vddc: 900 vddci: 0
# echo "high" > /sys/class/drm/card1/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level  
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
# # Not sure why the above happened!?
#
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/1/radeon_pm_info
uvd    vclk: 0 dclk: 0
power level 2    sclk: 75000 mclk: 80000 vddc: 1120 vddci: 0
# echo "high" > /sys/class/drm/card1/device/power_dpm_force_performance_level  
#
# echo "battery" > /sys/class/drm/card1/device/power_dpm_state
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/dri/1/radeon_pm_info
uvd    vclk: 0 dclk: 0
power level 0    sclk: 15700 mclk: 20000 vddc: 900 vddci: 0
#
```