# how to change my HD4870 fan speed

Tags: ati, fan

I just migrated from win10, and I'm having trouble with my gpu fan. I have a hd4870 card.

Its is just to damn loud. I would even unplug it if my motherboard had onboard video.

I'm doing some research and I didn't find a way to change fan speed. I dont know if I want to install the catalyst driver because I didn't find if my gpu is supported.

I don't plan on playing any games, I use the computer mainly for study nowadays, and its really annoying it being so loud.

I would really appreciate any help! Thanks

Comment: You may want to check if power management is enabled. http://askubuntu.com/questions/442817/how-to-activate-radeon-dynamic-power-management It should be, if you've installed 14.04 and later.

Comment: Which is you processor and every processor now a days support On-board graphics and all motherboard comes with a chip-set

Comment: Intel CPUs come with integrated “Intel HD Graphics” or “Iris Graphics” hardware, while AMD CPUs come with their own brand of integrated graphics. AMD calls these APUs (Accelerated Processing Units) because they contain CPU and GPU hardware on a single chip.

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Intel CPUs can be purchased with or without integrated graphics. Those of us who build our own PCs buy processors without graphics as we are going to have a graphics card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable DPM by adding a boot parameter. This should greatly help power consumption, especially when idle. To do so, edit `/etc/default/grub` and add the 'radeon.dpm=1' to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line, so it would look something like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.dpm=1"
```

After you save/quit the text editor, update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```